# What would short versions of given formulas be and how do you do it in general?

Tags: openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

I am studying for a test and I would really appreciate some help with this. The instructions are simply to write these formulas in a shorter version. I understand how IF works; if the expression is true, it returns the first value, otherwise the second one (they are separated by semicolons).

Given examples are:

```
    =D$5+IF(C4>1;F8-A12/4-53;F8-A12/4-B12+1) 

    =IF(C4="test";A4-55+C13;22+(C13+B2+A4)) 

    =C3*IF(AND(C4="P";C5="P");4*A4/(1-m);m*A4-n*A4); 

    =IF(B3<>0;2*C6;2*IF(B3=2;SIN(omega*t-$A$2);0)
```

Explanation will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first formula can be shortened to:

```
=D$5+F8-A12/4+IF(C4>1;-53;-B12+1)
```

It's just a matter of factoring out `F8-A12` since it is used twice.

To test this, I filled in some numbers into the cells mentioned, and it produced the correct result.

Similarly in the second formula, `A4` and `C13` are used twice and they could be factored out to be used only once.

In the third formula, everything is getting multiplied by `A4` so it could be factored out.

In the fourth formula, it looks like `2` is the only thing that could be factored out.